# How to identify what keyboard language is with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there any way to identify the keyboard language?
i have a simple textbox. that i want to check keyboard language. when the user click on textbox if the keyboard language was Contrary to Persian the user can't type anything and show the error:" change your keyboard language to persian" and when the keyboard language changed user can type.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can use the keydown event to prevent a user from inputting certain characters. In this case you could check and only allow Persian characters. There's tons of examples of this for allowing only numbers if you search on Google.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have used two different approaches for detecting English and Persian characters in my solution:

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
     if (isEnglish(e.charCode))
       console.log('English');
     else if(isPersian(e.key))
       console.log('Persian');
     else
       console.log('Others')
});

function isEnglish(charCode){
   return (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) 
          || (charCode>=65 && charCode<=90);
}

function isPersian(key){
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;    
    return p.test(key) && key!=' ';
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible - anyway it's probably not what you want (Caps Lock, for example, will still output English)
I'd recommend placing a `keypress` event listener on your textarea and checking each letter against a "Persian only" regex
like this (untested):

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
     if (e.charCode > 160) 
     console.log('persian');
     else
     console.log('english');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match ZERO WIDTH SPACE you should add this too:

```
\u200B
```

So

```
var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\u200B\s]+$/;
```

for more characters like ” | « | » | ?| ; | : | ... see [Regex Persian Language](https://github.com/hosseinmousavi/Regex.Persian.Language)

Answer (score 1):

using jquery :

```
$("#selector").keyup(function (event) {
    var code = event.key.charCodeAt(0);
    if (isEnglish(code)) {
        alert("you typed in english");
        return;
    }
    else {
        alert("please type in english");
    }
});

function isEnglish(charCode) {
    return (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)
        || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function only_persian(str){
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
  if (!p.test(str)) {
        alert("not format");
    }
}
```

or you can use this: http://imanmh.github.io/persianRex/